# Why C++ gives segmentation fault when multiplying matrices more than size of 590x590?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, matrix-multiplication

What is the best way to declare c++ 2d arrays which can have a less effect from the fixed and limited stack size. I recently got segmentation fault due to stackoverflow in following code.
How does vectors tackle this issue?

Here is the code which I developed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void printMatrix(double *mat);
void generateMat(double *mat);
void multiplyMat(double *a,double *b,double *c);

int n;

int start_s;
    // the code you wish to time goes here
int stop_s;


int main(){ 

    for(int i=500;i<1000;i++){

    cout<< "Enter n:";
    //cin >> n;
    n=i;
    cout<< "n="<<n<<endl;

    double a[n][n],b[n][n],c[n][n]; //c = a * b, c is the
    // result matrix

    generateMat(*a);
    generateMat(*b);

    // initializing c matrix with 0s'
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            c[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Matrix 1"<<endl;
    //printMatrix(*a);

    cout<<endl<<"Matrix 2"<<endl;
    //printMatrix(*b);

    multiplyMat(*a,*b,*c);

    cout<<endl<<"Result Matrix"<<endl;
    //printMatrix(*c);

    cout << endl<<"Execution time: " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}

void multiplyMat(double *a,double *b,double* c){
    start_s=clock();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
                *(c+i*n+j)+=(*(a+i*n+k)) * (*(b+k*n+j));
            }
        }
    }
    stop_s=clock();
}

void printMatrix(double *mat){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cout<< *(mat+i*n+j)<< " ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void generateMat(double *mat){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            *(mat+i*n+j)=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX*10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: @DinukaSalwathura: don't comment your own question. **Edit your question** to improve it. Put code there with four spaces before each line.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @RushikeshDeshpande added the code. Thank for the suggestions.

Comment: add error you are getting and do analyse why the error is coming before posting question

Comment: @RushikeshDeshpande thanks

Comment: First, don't use `variable sized array` (not recommendable - all C++ compilers will not allow this).
Second, you are declaring the array in main function, so the memory will be placed on stack (as it is not dynamic allocated) which is very limited by default (8 mb on my linux). Increase the stack size and re-run the program and observe the output by debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrices are using space on the local [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (which is often limited to one, or a few, megabytes).

You should consider making a `class` for them, which uses heap allocated data (and release it in the destructor). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) is for C, not C++, but should be inspirational (just recode it in genuine C++, perhaps using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and/or some C++ standard [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)[s]).

You might represent a matrix with some internal [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) data, and provide operations (i.e. member functions) to resize that matrix and access or modify its element of indices *i* & *j*

Comment: Or you can try make it a sparse matrix.

Comment: That is by far too much guessing for such a under-specified question.