# fscanf and fgets for a text file (int, string, string and float) in c

Tags: c, string, file, scanf, fgets

I'm trying to create 4 arrays with a text file. The text file look like this :

```
1000 Docteur             Albert              65.5
1001 Solo                Hanz                23.4
1002 Caillou             Frederic            78.7
…
```

The code:

```
void creer (int num[], char pre[][TAILLE_NP+1], char nom[][TAILLE_NP+1], 
float note[], int * nb ){

  int  n = 0, i; /*nb personnes*/

  FILE *donnees = fopen("notes.txt", "r");

  if(!donnees){
    printf("Erreur ouverture de fichier\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  while (!feof(donnees)){

    fscanf(donnees,"%d", &num [n]);
    fgets(nom[n], TAILLE_NP+1, donnees);
    fgets(pre[n], TAILLE_NP+1, donnees);
    fscanf(donnees,"%f\n", &note[n]);

    printf("%d %s %s %f\n",num[n], nom[n], pre[n], note[n]);
    n++;
    }

  fclose (donnees);

  *nb = n ;
  }


int main() {

  int num[MAX_NUM];
  int nbEle;

  char pre[MAX_NUM][TAILLE_NP+1],
       nom[MAX_NUM][TAILLE_NP+1];

  float note[MAX_NUM];

  creer (num, pre, nom, note, &nbEle);

  printf("%s", pre[2]); //test

  return 0; 
}
```

The problem is, I'm sure there is a better way to create the arrays, im a beginner. Also, there is a problem with the float, the decimal aren't right when I printf. For example, 78.7 become 78.699997.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. Mixing `fscanf()` and `fgets()` is a bad idea, as the former works on parts of a line and latter on a complete line.
2. `float` isn't as precise as you might expect it to be.

---

To solve 1:

```
fscanf(donnees, "%d", &num[n]);
fscanf(donnees, "%s", nom[n]);
fscanf(donnees, "%s", pre[n]);
fscanf(donnees, "%f\n", &note[n]);
```

To avoid overflowing the "strings" you can tell `fscanf()` how much to scan in as a maximum by using, for example, `"%42s"` for a string of 42 `char`s (not counting the `0`-terminating `char`).

---

To solve 2:

Make `note` be `double`s and do

```
fscanf(donnees,"%lf\n", &note[n]);
```

Comment: Solve 2 worked! Thanks. 
But solve 1 didn't work. When I change the code, the execution is very messy with 0.0000 for note[n]

Comment: @SamuelGirard: "*didn't work*" means exactly what, please?

Comment: Nevermind, It was only the printf. Forgot to change %f to %lf. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SamuelGirard There is ***no*** need to use the length modifier `l` when printing `double`s. It shall work *correctly* without it.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here:

Floating point is very tricky. Read [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/) (and remember that URL).

Don't allocate huge [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) on your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). A typical call frame should have no more than few kilobytes (and your entire call stack should be less than one or a few megabytes). Use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

C has only one-dimensional arrays. If you need better, make some abstract data type (generally, avoid arrays of arrays). Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) for inspiration.

Read carefully the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every standard function. You should test the result of [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).