# Malloc for struct

Tags: c, malloc

I´m working on my program, that loads data from external `.txt file` - it is structure of 3 integers. Now Im struggling with function that allocates memory. I want to allocate memory for structure of 9 members (108 bytes).

My main program was too large to mess with so I created a smaller program to help me more easily figure out what is going on. Previous questions I went through seemed too complicated and unclear to me, that´s why I made my own.

Id like to know why the third `printf`, prints 4 and how to correctly allocate required memory (108 bytes)

Glad for any advice

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

    int main(){
        int object_counter = 9;

        typedef struct myStruct {
         int name;
         int age;
         int height;
        } myStruct;

        myStruct* dynamicStruct;
        dynamicStruct = malloc(object_counter*sizeof(myStruct));
        if (dynamicStruct == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            return (-1);
        } else {
            printf("SUCCESS\n");
        }
        printf("Size is: %lu\n", sizeof(myStruct));             // prints 12, thats 3 times int, OK
        printf("Size is: %lu\n", object_counter*sizeof(struct myStruct));   // prints 108, obviously 9 times 4 bytes
        printf("Size is: %lu\n", sizeof(dynamicStruct));        // prints 4 ?? (expected 108)
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That is the size of the pointer (memory address) not of the data it points to (your struct)

Comment: `dynamicStruct` is a *pointer* which is usually 4 bytes on 32-bit systems. `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` any pointer is constant (8 bytes on my Linux/x86-64 system, which is also the `sizeof(uintptr_t)`, etc....). It is unrelated to the runtime size of the pointed memory zone. In other words, the [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) *always* gives a *compile-time* constant (except for [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s).

You practically need to keep elsewhere the *allocated* size of a `malloc`-ed pointer. For example, you could keep the pointer value in one variable, and its allocated size in another variable.

You could consider an abstract data type (using [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)) approach like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108).

Comment: For VLAs `sizeof` is not a constant.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Pointer is always the same size, VLAs here have no meaning. We are talking about pointer size here, not actual memory.

Comment: My point is that `sizeof` on VLAs don't give a compile time constant. That is the only exception to the rule

Comment: Right..it will be an expression in case of VLA..ok gotcha. +1