# Calloc() error force closing program, invisible to debugger

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement a function that multiplies two dynamic matrices (AxB) and returns a pointer to the dynamically allocated product (C). The arguments of the function are:

1. pointer to matrix A
2. a_rows, number of rows in A
3. a_cols number of columns in A
4. pointer to matrix B
5. b_cols, number of columns in B

Since the product will have the same number of rows as A and the same number of columns as B, a_rows and b_cols are used to determine the size of the product to be allocated.

The function is as shown:

```
double** MatrixMultiply(
    double** a,
    const uint32_t a_rows,
    const uint32_t a_cols,
    double** b,
    const uint32_t b_cols) {

    double** c;
    c = (double**) calloc(a_rows, sizeof(double**));  //product matrix C has 
    //matrix A rows and Matrix B cols

    for(int32_t i = 0; i < a_rows; i++) {
        c[i] = (double*) calloc(b_cols, sizeof(double*));
    }

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < a_rows; i++) {
        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < b_cols; j++) {
            for(uint32_t k = 0; k < a_cols; k++) {
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I run my program it gets crashed by the function because of what I assume is some sort of segmentation fault. However, whenever I run the debugger and step through each line, it never shows that any errors have occurred.

What is strange to me is that when I change "a_rows" and "b_cols" to a constant (e.g., 20) the function runs correctly. What could be causing this problem? And how can it be fixed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All of your memory allocations are broken: You're passing the wrong type to `sizeof`, and you shouldn't cast `calloc()`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You're *never* initializing `a_rows`,`b_cols`...

Answer (score 4):

You are allocating the wrong amount of memory.

```
c[i] = (double*) calloc(b_cols, sizeof(double*));
```

This allocates memory for `b_cols` of double-pointers, not `b_cols` of doubles.

This is the typical error when using `typedef(<type>)`, one make mistakes very
easy, because you add a `*` where is not needed or you forget to add `*` when it's needed.

It's better practice to use `sizeof *var` than `sizeof(<type>)`:

```
int *arr = malloc(size * sizeof *arr);
```

The `sizeof *arr` returns the exact amount of bytes regardless of the type. It
also has the benefit that if you later happen to change the type of the
variable, you don't have to worry about changing the expression inside
`sizeof`.

The correct way is:

```
c = calloc(a_rows, sizeof *c);

if(c == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}

for(int32_t i = 0; i < a_rows; i++) {
    c[i] = calloc(b_cols, sizeof *c[i]);
    if(c[i] == NULL)
    {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Also [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and always check that the result is not `NULL`. If
you don't check and the result is `NULL`, then you will try to access a `NULL`
pointer which is undefined behaviour and will lead to a segfault. Also don't
forget to free the memory afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong. `calloc` (and `malloc`) can fail, and you always should handle that. You don't need to cast it, and the second argument is the size of each cell (not of a pointer to it).

A minima you should have

```
double** c=  calloc(a_rows, sizeof(double*));
if (c==NULL) { perror("calloc c"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

and likewise

```
c[i] = calloc(b_cols, sizeof(double));
if (c[i]==NULL) { perror("calloc c row"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Notice that for each `calloc` the second argument is the size of *one* cell (not of the pointer to it). The first argument is the number of cells (are you sure you want `b_cols`, not `a_cols`? only you can know).

For the allocation of `c` as a whole, in *practice* all pointers have the same size, so `sizeof(double**)` is generally the same value (8 bytes on my Linux/x86-64) than `sizeof(double*)`.

You should compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Some compilers (recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) could have warned you. And you could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to run (with checks) your program (that could have detected the buffer overflow). Of course you also should [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

BTW, a better way of having matrixes is to make them some abstract data type like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108).

> However, whenever I run the debugger and step through each line, it never shows that any errors have occurred.

On Linux (or MacOSX), you could set up your system so that a core dump occurs (be sure to have a large enough limit for your core files, perhaps with the `ulimit` builtin of `bash`), and analyze post mortem that core dump with `gdb`; see [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html), [gdb(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html), [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). And `gdb` is able to run your program till it crashes.

Comment: That was a well-placed link to the abstract data solution.. `:)`