# how to implement matrix functions in C

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to make some simple functions that does some operations on matrixes. But i can`t undestand why the following code is not working!. Can you please help me to understand what is wrong here and what should i do???

```
void create(int*** p, const int n)
{
    *p = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    if(*p == NULL){
        printf("Error1");
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        (*(p[i]) = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int)));

        if(*(p[i]) == NULL){
            printf("Error2");
        }
    }
}
void initializeMatrix(int*** p, const int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &((p[i][j])));
        }
    }
}
void show(const int** p, const int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%d ", ((p)[i][j]));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    int** p = NULL;

    create(&p, 2);
initializeMatrix(&p, 2);

    show(p, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: it just terminates!?

Comment: you size is wrong here  *p = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int)); should be  *p = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));

Comment: Being a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment. Instead of your `create` function emulating pass-by-reference let it *return* the created matrix.

Comment: did you try stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: As for your problem, all allocation functions (including [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc)) are measuring the size in *bytes*. The size the memory allocated by `calloc` is `n * sizeof(int)` bytes (in your case).

Comment: By the way, in C you [don't need to cast the result of `calloc` (or other memory allocation functions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Another major problem, take a close look at your `initializeMatrix` function. Are you using the pointer `p` correctly there? Again, don't emulate pass-by-reference.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) to a duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem 1

You are using `*(p[i])` in `create`. it should be `(*p)[i]`.

```
void create(int*** p, const int n)
{
    *p = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    if(*p == NULL){
        printf("Error1");
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){

        // FIXED 
        (*p)[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int)));

        // FIXED
        if( (*p)[i] == NULL){
            printf("Error2");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem 2

You are passing the wrong size to first `calloc` in the function. You need to use `sizeof(int*)`. After all, you want the returned value to be a pointer to `n` pointers to `int`, not a pointer to `n` objects of type `int`.

This is a critical error that leads to undefined behavior unless `sizeof(int)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)` on your platform.

Change the line to

```
    *p = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
```

---

More importantly, you can make that function a bit easier by returning a pointer. It will be easier to write such a function.

```
int** create(int n)
    int **p = calloc(n, sizeof(*p));
    if(p == NULL){
        printf("Error1");
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){

        p[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(*p[i])));

        if( p[i] == NULL){
            printf("Error2");
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

and use it as:

```
int** p = create(2);
```

Comment: Probably one [Calloc() call it will be cheaper](https://ideone.com/MhY6il)

Comment: @Michi, it definitely will. Then the OP has to map the two indices to one index appropriately.

Comment: @R Sahu You right but I'm sure that the OP needs to understand all of this.

Comment: @Michi Your `arr = calloc(sizeof( *arr ), sizeof *arr * row * col);` call uses  incorrect size calculation.

Comment: UV for good use of `sizeof(* object_pointer)` rather than `sizeof( object_pointer_type)`