# c Functions with arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to make a function that works with arrays of undefined length?
For example, I made this code to fill a matrix of 3x3 and I wonder if is there a way to do this but with a matrix of nxn.

```
void fillMatrix(double mat[][COLS])
{
    int i,j;    

        printf("Enter the %d matrix elements:\n",COLS*ROWS);
        for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<COLS;j++)
            {
                scanf("%lf",&mat[i][j]);
            }                   
        }
        printf("\n");   
}
```

In this code I defined ROWS=COLS=3.

Comment: this one void fillMatrix(double **mat, int *row, int *col);

Comment: Functions *never* take arrays as arguments. Arrays are decayed into pointers when passed as argument in a function call. See some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you know the number of columns in the 2D array at the time of passing it to the function. You do not have to define COL beforehand.

```
void foo(int col, int arr[][col]) {
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
void func(void *data, int row, int col)
{
    int (*a)[col] = (int(*)[col])data;
    //now you can access a[i][j] with i<row and j<col
    //data must be an continous array
    //replace int with your data type
}
```

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int (*a)[n];
    int b[5][5];

    a = (int(*)[n])b;
    b[0][0]=0;
    b[0][1]=1;
    b[2][1]=111;
    b[1][2]=666;
    b[4][3]=222;

    printf("%d\n", a[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", a[0][1]);
    printf("%d\n", a[2][1]);
    printf("%d\n", a[1][2]);
    printf("%d\n", a[4][3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can add a new parameter `row` to your function `fillMatrix(double mat[][COLS])`, that is, `fillMatrix(double mat[][col], int row)`

another way:

```
double** matrix = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double*)*n);
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    matrix[i] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
}
```

then change the function to: `fillMatrix(double** matrix, int n)`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make a function that works with arrays of undefined length?

You'll better know the dimension of the array. If it is a function argument, you should in general pass the dimension in some other argument.

Remember that when passed as argument, an array is decayed into a pointer. Look also into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site and later refer to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

In your case, you want to define then have an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) (probably some [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)) for your matrixes. Using [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) could be useful. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) answer for details.

Comment: Just saw I can made a function that reserves memory for the array using `malloc` and then I can use that function with my `fillMatrix`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it using dinamic memory.

you will something like:

```
void fillMatrix(double** mat, int rows, int cols)    {
    int i,j;    

    printf("Enter the %d matrix elements:\n",rows*cols);
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf",&mat[i][j]);
        }                   
    }
    printf("\n");   
 }
```

where double** mat is a vector of vectors that you will have to ask for memory using malloc for the rows and the malloc for the columns.