# Assign a pointer by a pointer to multidimensional array in function

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array, pointer-to-pointer

```
void print_first_n_row(double **matrix, int n, int row_size) {
 double (*abc)[row_size];
 abc=matrix;}
```

I am having assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  abc=matrix error. How can I solve this?

Comment: By changing `void print_first_n_row(double **matrix, int n, int row_size)` to `void print_first_n_row(int n, int row_size, double (*matrix)[row_size])` and accordingly modifying caller? (It depends on how the function and `abc` are used)

Comment: I do not see why any body would vote to close this. It is a question that contains commonly encountered mysteries for any new C programmer, therefore therefore will be of interest to other new programmers.

Comment: You need to show us the code that calls `print_first_n_row`, and how the parameter corresponding to `matrix` has been declared.

Answer (score 4):

A matrix is an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type). How you implement it is an implementation detail.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) answer I detailed how you could implement such a type in C.

**Multi-dimensional arrays don't really exist in C.** C just have arrays of arrays, or arrays of pointers -or other types, including arrays of scalars. Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the C11 standard).

> I am having assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] abc=matrix error. How can I solve this?

Either think in abstract data types terms, or read more about C [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (consider using [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)) and about the [C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

You'll find many examples of matrix-related source code on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) and elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This answer is just regarding the error message, not the logic behind passing pointers to a matrix.*

---

> "*I am having assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] abc=matrix error. How can I solve this?*"

`double (*abc)[row_size];` - `abc` is a pointer to an array of `double`.

`double **matrix` - `matrix` is a pointer to a pointer to `double`.

There is a mismatch. `*` vs. `**`.

You can´t assign the value of a pointer to a pointer to `double` to a pointer to an array of `double`.

Change `double (*abc)[row_size];` to `double **abc` or `double (**abc)[row_size];` or just use `matrix` if `abc` isn´t needed otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is that `matrix` and `abc` have to be declared the same way.  Either you need to change the prototype to

```
void print_first_n_row(int n, int row_size, double (*matrix)[row_size]) // row_size needs to be defined first
{
  double (*abc)[row_size] = matrix;
  ...
}
```

or you need to change the definition of `abc` to

```
double **abc;
```

It depends on how you're calling defining the parameter `matrix` corresponds to and how you're calling `print_first_n_row`.

Assuming your code looks something like:

```
int main( void )
{
  int rows = ...;  // assumes rows and cols are set at runtime
  int cols = ...;
  ...
  double matrix[rows][cols];
  ...
  print_first_n_rows( matrix, n, cols )
  ...
}
```

then the first solution is correct, and you need to change the call to

```
  print_first_n_rows( n, cols, matrix );
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been explained in detail in other answers that trying to make assignments using incompatible types is wrong. Even if the compiler did not warn you, these assignments can often result in undefined behavior. ***But*** in C, multi-dimensional arrays are stored in single contiguous blocks of memory_, eg:

```
in array[4][2] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
```

Is stored in memory as a single sequential block of locations:

```
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
```

*Not* as you might imagine, in multiple blocks:

```
|1|2|3|4|
|5|6|7|8|
```

It is therefore possible to create a single pointer variable that can be set to *point* to any location within a C array (of the same base type), and can for example be used to assign values to that array, as shown in the following adaptation using [Variable Length Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/):

```
int main(void)
{
    print_first_n_row(4,2);// params to create 4X2 array

    return 0;
}

void print_first_n_row(int r, int c) 
{
    double matrix[r][c];        //create array using Variable Length Array
    double *abc = &matrix[0][0];//create pointer of same base type
                                //and set address to pointer to point to 
                                //first location of matrix
    printf("%s", "array contents:");
    for(int i=0; i<r*c; i++)
    {
        *(abc + i) = i*i;
        printf("%0.2f,", *(abc + i));

    }
}
```

Or, in keeping with your example of passing the array as an argument, as long as the types are the same, the capability of using a pointer to index through the array locations holds true as well:

Passing array argument:

```
void print_first_n_row(double matrix[4][2]);

int main(void)
{
    double array1[4][2] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    print_first_n_row(array1);

    return 0;
}

void print_first_n_row(double matrix[4][2]) 
{
    double *abc = &matrix[0][0];//create pointer of same base type
                                //and set address to pointer to point to 
                                //first location of matrix
    ...(same as first example)
```