# How can i correct this memory leak?

Tags: c, malloc, free

This is my code to allocate memory using malloc for a 2 dimensional array in C, and to free it. N is a number given by the user

```c
R = malloc(N * sizeof(int *)); // start of memory allocating for **R
if (R == NULL) { 
  return -1;
}

for (i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
  *(R+i) = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
  if (*(R + i) == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
} // end of memory allocating for **R 

for (i = 0 ; i < N; i++){
  free(R[i]);
  free(R);
}
```

After the program finishes, I get this error: `double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)`

By using valgrind for debugging, I get this message: `12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1`

This leak is detected at this line of code (according to valgrind): `*(C+i) = malloc(N * sizeof(int));`

Any help on how to fix it?

Comment: This code is incomplete. You allocate `R`, then you free `C` ...

Comment: Please post a [mcve], and perhaps indent it properly while you are at it.

Answer (score 2):

> i get this error: double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)

first notice that error is not a memory leak, the double free comes from that code

```
for (i=0 ; i <N ; i++){
  free(R[i]);
  free(R);
}
```

which must be must be

```
for (i=0 ; i <=N ; i++){
  free(R[i]);
}
free(R);
```

else you free *R* in the first loop rather than *after* the loops

Because of that from the second loop the value of `R[i]` if undefined and the behavior of the *free* is undefined too, and you call again *free* on *R*, both reasons compatible with the message produced by *valgrind*.

Note I also changed the test to be `i<=N` to be the identical of the test used to do the allocations, but both suppose your array is sized `N+1` (at least), else you miss a *free* producing a memory leak.

If the allocations step and free step are not consecutive in the code and the free step is done even you cannot allocate the memory at a given time, the code must be modified to be :

```
if (R != NULL)
{
  for (i=0 ; i <=N ; i++){
    if (R[i] == NULL) /* allocation failed */
      break;
    free(R[i]);
  }
  free(R);
}
```

to not dereference *R* if it is NULL, and to not attempts to free the entries of the array not set in the allocation loop because `(*(R + i) == NULL)` was true breaking the loop

Comment: Your assumption is correct ,however that seems to not be the solution to my subproblem

Comment: @DavidBrawl why ? did you see the remark about the size ?

Comment: There's one other issue, although it won't show up unless the allocation stage partially failed: either an early return should itself free `R` and all the allocated `R[0]..R[i]`, or the early return branch should make sure the subsequent `R[i+1]..R[N]` are set to NULL.

Comment: @Useless yes, but in the given code there is a *return* so none free are done at all

Comment: I was assuming that was a snippet from a different function - it's hard to be sure without a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Useless yes, and I edited my answer to follow your advice

Comment: It's OK to `free(NULL)`, right? The issue is that the uninitialized `R[i]` (or `C[i]` or whatever) entries may _not_ be `NULL`.

Comment: @Useless yes it is ok, but the next elements are not initialized, so it is not possible to call *free* on them, and because it is useless to call *free* on NULL I check the NULL case before to call *free*

Comment: @Useless it is like you do not see the *break* in my code, I do not do `if (C[i] != NULL) free(C[i]);` or something like that

Comment: @DavidBrawl please can you answer to my remark about the size of the array (also in my answer)  ?

Comment: @bruno Sorry to the late response,it seems that my problem steemed from me,not calculating correctly the lines of the 2d array

Comment: Ah you mean because the single failed allocation stops the `free` loop. Yes, you're perfectly right - I was fixated on the partially-successful allocation itself.

Answer (score 1):

> This is my code to allocate memory using malloc for a 2 dimensional array in C, and to free it

An alternative approach is to make your matrix some [*abstract data type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) implemented by some (pointer to) `struct` ending with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). In such a case, your matrix creation routine makes *one* allocation (using `malloc`), and your matrix deallacation routine can be a simple (casted) `free`. Don't forget to handle failure of [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) (it could happen when you want a gigantic matrix which don't fit in your computer).

Details have been given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108).

Read also of course [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and some [C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

IMHO two-dimensional arrays don't exist in C, you can just have arrays of arrays of some known type. Check by reading some C standard, like [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf).