# C iki boyutlu dizi Malloc

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

I don't know where I'm wrong and I get segmentation fault error. Can you help?

My Code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void do_array(int x, int y, int **arr){
    arr=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*x);
    for (int i=0;i<y;i++){
        *(arr+i)=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*y);
    }
}

int main(){
    int **p;
    do_array(5,2,p);
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            *(*(p+i)+j)=i;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("%d\n",*(*(p+i)+j));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

!!! I want to do is create a dynamic 2D array

Comment: `do` is a keyword in C. You can't use it for a function name.

Comment: You're passing `p` by value, that's not gonna work. Also, I don't know how you get a segmentation fault when this code does not even compile...

Comment: @EmanuelP i will edit but it's same

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) to a related question. For your next question, provide some [mre]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int main(){
>     int **p /* = NULL */ ;         // p is garbage       or NULL
>     do_array(5,2,p);               // p is still garbage or NULL
>     for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
>         for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
>             *(*(p+i)+j)=i;         // p is still garbage or NULL
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The formal argument `arr` in the function is a separate object from the actual argument `p` in `main` - any changes to `arr` are not applied to `p`, so `p` is never set to point to the memory you just allocated.

What you will have to do is pass a *pointer to* `p`:

```
void doArr(int x, int y, int ***arr){
    *arr=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*x); // note type of sizeof - you're allocating an array of int *, not int
    for (int i=0;i<y;i++){
      *(*arr+i)=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*y);
    }
}
...
doArr( 5, 2, &p );
```

*Or*, return `arr` and assign the result of `doArr` to `p`:

```
int **p = doArr( int x, int y )
{
  int **arr = malloc(...);
  ...
  return arr;
}

p = doArr( 5, 2 );
```

As Emanuel P notes, `do` is a keyword, so you can't use it as a function name.

---

A couple of style notes:

Since C89, `malloc` returns `void *` and does not require an explicit cast, and many of us will recommend against using it.  It just adds visual noise and creates an extra maintenance burden.

Similarly, I often recommend that the operand of `sizeof` be your target expression, not a type name.  Again, this eases your maintenance headaches if you change the type of the destination pointer.

Use array notation instead of pointer arithmetic where possible.  It's easier to read and follow, and you're less likely to make a mistake.

Finally, *always* check the result of a `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` call.

I'd rewrite your `doArr` function as follows:

```
void doArr(int x, int y, int ***arr)
{
  *arr = malloc( sizeof **arr * x ); 
  if ( *arr )
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < y; i++ )
    {
      (*arr)[i] = malloc( sizeof *(*arr)[i] * y );
    }
  }
}
```

and call it as

```
doArr( 5, 2, &p );
```

Comment: I would rather advice to return the double pointer instead. It is better to avoid side effects where possible

Answer (score 0):

> I want to do is create a dynamic 2D array

In your code you do not create a 2D array only the array of pointers.

```
void *doArr(size_t x, size_t y)
{
  int (*arr)[x][y] = malloc( sizeof((*arr)[0][0]) * x * y); 
  return arr;
}
```